# My embedded YouTube videos stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

I'm developing a website and the home page has a few embedded youtube videos. The videos worked great until recently, but now it seems they no longer work! It fetches the video from YouTube, but I'm not able to play any of them.

I compared the code to an earlier version and the code is still the same. I've been searching and scratching my head on this for hours trying to figure out why it won't work anymore. Here's a JSFiddle with the code I'm using.
https://jsfiddle.net/ftmLsaym/

Any ideas what I need to do to fix this?

HTML

```
<div class="splashdiv">
    <iframe id="teaser" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PNT39y4N4H4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%">
    <button style="width:50%;float:left" onclick="previousVideo()">Previous</button>
    <button style="width:50%;float:right" onclick="nextVideo()">Next</button></div>
```

CSS

```
.splashdiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 51%;
  z-index:-1;
}

.splashdiv iframe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0; top: 0;
}
```

JS

```
        var frame = document.getElementById('teaser');
        var pos = 0;
        var src = [
            "https://www.youtube.com/embed/PNT39y4N4H4?rel=0",
            "https://www.youtube.com/embed/M--kEKu8-IE?rel=0",
            "https://www.youtube.com/embed/3wgd8fHidzg?rel=0",
            "https://www.youtube.com/embed/2yf4bUW9mlE?rel=0",
            "https://www.youtube.com/embed/CueAcWRsaY8?rel=0",
            "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ulsa6Aog7Yw?rel=0",
            "https://www.youtube.com/embed/7qTp3lk7gt4?rel=0"
        ]

        function nextVideo() {
            if (pos < 6) {
                pos += 1;
                showVideo();
            }
        }
        function previousVideo() {
            if (pos > 0) {
                pos -= 1;
                showVideo();
            }
        }
        function showVideo() {
            frame.src = src[pos];
        }
        function barnaby() {
            pos = 1;
            frame.src = src[pos]+"&autoplay=1";
        }
```

Comment: Can't believe I hadn't thought of z-index... Thanks for the quick answers! Got another issue though.. as you can see, the barnaby function adds autoplay to the src, but after this is triggered I just get "This video is unavailable" any thoughts? Am I using the right parameter for autoplay?

Comment: Edit: Came to find the video was somehow set to private... problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete this line:

```
z-index:-1
```

`z-index:-1` sets the whole `.splashdiv` div (including the iframe) to be behind the body layer. So the YouTube iframe cannot capture your mouse click.

Answer (score 1):

The `z-index` is too low, you need to increase it, it's behind another `div` a solution is shown here although you don't need to use 200, just an example : ) https://jsfiddle.net/ftmLsaym/5/

Answer (score 0):

Move the iframe out of the splashdiv - that should let the video run.

Answer (score 0):

replace your `.splashdiv` css code with this

```
.splashdiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 51%;
  z-index:2;
}
```